# How to fix 'Unable to locate package' error in apt-cyg

Tags: cygwin, apt

Im using Cygwin and I need to install a g++ compiler, so I tried with apt-cyg.

It returns an error that happens with some packages but not with others. For instance, I could install git package, which I found in blogs that talk about this topic to try it as an example. However, when trying g++:

```
   $ apt-cyg install g++
   Installing g++
   Unable to locate package g++
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would suggest you use the standard Cygwin `setup-x86_64.exe` (or its 32-bit version if appropriate) rather than `apt-cyg`.  Scanning the "Devel" category in setup, you will see a package `gcc-g++`, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I can use the installer for that.

Comment: @AlejandrodelosReyes For the benefit of both respondents and future readers: If an answer
    solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark
    next to it; if you find an answer helpful, please up-vote it by clicking
    the up-arrow icon (you may do both).  See [the relevant help-center
    article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @varro is correct. However, if you wish to use `apt-cyg`, you should take advantage of it's search capabilities.

```
apt-cyg search g++
```

returns `gcc-g++`.

Thus, you can execute the following `apt-cyg` command to install g++:

```
apt-cyg install gcc-g++
```